# Появляющаяся кнопка в форме

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть обычная форма, в ней несколько инпутов (текстбоксов), и в самом конце, как обычно кнопка. Как сделать, чтобы кнопка была неактивна первые 10 секунд или появлялась не сразу, а только через 10 секунд?

P.S. штуковина типа "`sleep(10);`" не подходит, т.к. тянет время загрузки всей страницы.

Comment: в javascript нету sleep, LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="foo" type="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Нужная кнопка ищется по ID элемента ("foo").

```
// document.getElementById("foo").disabled = true; // Raw JavaScript
$("#foo").prop("disabled", true); // jQuery 1.6+
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // document.getElementById("foo").disabled = false; // Raw JavaScript
    $("#foo").prop("disabled", false); // jQuery 1.6+
}, 10000);
```

Примеры: [с использованием jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/drdaeman/dGRc5/) и [с чистой манипуляцией DOM, без библиотек](http://jsfiddle.net/drdaeman/dGRc5/1/).

Comment: спасибо. помогло 8-)

Answer (score 3):

есть такая штуковина: setTimeout

просто пишете:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("button").show()},10000)
```

да, имелось в виду, что изначально кнопка скрыта через display: none;

Comment: если честно, я с JS пока еще на "вы" ) можно чуть подробнее? в инпут вписал display: none; добавил скрипт. теперь я так понимаю нужно указать скрипту, что именно нужно показывать